# React Material UI Select native - doesn't show empty when value is not found

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I am using Material UI Select native in my project this way:

```
 <Select
     value={values.teamId}
     native
     onChange={handleSelectChange}>
       <option aria-label="None" value=""/>
       {(teamsList || []).map(ele => (
               <option key={ele.teamId} value={ele.teamId}>{ele.teamDesc}</option>
       ))}
 </Select>
```

and this is the result (it has form control component as parent, which doesn't affect the issue in hand):
[image]

The issue here is that I expect the component to be empty, and not showing me the first option as default

This way, the component has a value, wrong one, and when I submit my form I cannot make validation on it to see if the user forgot to pick a value here.

In my other select native components this works, but here its not because I've found out that the `values.teamId = 10` but `teamsList` **doesn't have** team object with teamId = 10.
I've tried removing the first option - `<option aria-label="None" value=""/>` but this way it just shows me the other first team from my `teamsList` object..

P.S this doesn't happen with regular select (not native), but the issue there is that it handles many (20-30+) records poorly in performance and usability (searching with keyboard for instance) so I cannot use it.

Is there any trick to solve this?

https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#advanced-features

Comment: What is the initial value of `values.teamId`? Should be `""` correct?

Comment: Yes, I try to inject avalue from the server to teamsId but if its empty I set a default value of ''
This way: teamId: response?.teamId || ''

Comment: Ok, have you tried to use `defaultValue` prop? Try to set it to `""`

Comment: I have tried that, sadly didn't work. I assume its not working since values.teamId has an actual value so the value prop of the select component is not empty (hence defaultValue is not triggered)

Comment: Could be, but if `values.teamId` is `null` Select should take `defaultValue`. I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, some of the teamId values (given by the db) were strings, in those cases the select native couldn't compare them as the teamList has id as number.

So basically all I had to do it cast the values.teamId to number type and it worked.

conclusion: always check the type, guys..